# Identifying Chinese tea

Tags: characters, culture

Can someone help me identify this tea? I received it as a gift and would love to know what I am drinking. It looks rather refined.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is called '浮翠硒茶' (翠眉)

'浮翠' came from idiom '[浮翠流丹](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%B5%AE%E7%BF%A0%E6%B5%81%E4%B8%B9)' which is used to describe bright colors

'硒茶' means 'selenium tea' (tea that contains selenium)

From this web page https://chagardens.com/pages/benefit-of-teas-with-selenium

> Selenium Benefits
>
> Selenium was discovered in 1817 but at that time was considered to be a hazardous element. In 1973, after decades of tests and studies, the World Health Organization declared selenium not only to be non hazardous, but a trace element, essential to the human body.
>
> Today selenium is known as a cancer slayer.

(翠眉) means 'green tea leaf in shape and size like an eyebrow' ,  basically means 'loose green tea leaf'

> '浮翠硒茶' (翠眉) = 'Green selenium tea ' (loose green tea leaves)

On the upper right corner it said: '无公害农产品' (Pollution-free agricultural products)

On the upper left corner states the brand name '茅山长寿' (Maoshan  Long Life)

江苏名商標 means 'Jiangsu's famous trademark'

句容市浮山果园出品 (Produced by Jurong City Fushan Orchard)

*So, this tea is supposedly good for fighting cancer (?)*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Awesome. And yes, to my knowledge green tea is is beneficial for preventing cancer, though the evidence appears to be mixed [https://www.cancerresearchuk.org/about-cancer/cancer-in-general/treatment/complementary-alternative-therapies/individual-therapies/green-tea]

Comment: @Sven -- The selling point of this tea is it contains 硒 (selenium). I haven't read enough research to believe it really can fight cancer, that's why I sounded doubtful in my comment

Comment: Can verify, this one is coming from a place near my hometown, pretty good green tea production area.